# Multi-level scraping with Node.js, request-promises and cheerio: How to make file-writing-function wait until all requests are done?

Tags: node.js, request, cheerio, request-promise

I am trying to scrape three levels of a webpage that link to each other, e.g. Home -> Jobs -> Open Positions. I then want to write the scraped data into a output.json file. The scraping works just fine, but the writing of the file is finished before the requests are due to their asynchronous nature.

The code below, using normal requests scrapes all the data, but is too "late" and thus the info does not get written into the file.

```
request(url, function(error, response, html){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $("tr").each(function(i, elem){
            var club_url = $(this).children().first().children().attr("href");
            club_url = url.substring(0,25) + club_url;
            request(club_url, function(error, response, html){
                if(!error){
                    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                    var club_name = $("h1.masthead-title").first().text().trim();
                    console.log(club_name);
                    clubs[i] = club_name;
                    var teams = {};
                    $("tr").each(function(i,elem){
                        var team_url = $(this).children().first().children().attr("href");
                        team_url = url.substring(0,25) + team_url;
                        request(team_url, function(error,response,html){
                            if(!error){
                                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                                var team = $(".team-name").text().trim();
                                console.log(team);
                                teams[i] = team;
                            }
                        });
                    }); 
                }
            }); 
        });
        fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(clubs, null, 4), function(err){
            console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
        });
```

Therefore I tried to use request-promise and re-write the code with it, so the writing would executed after the request promises are resolved.

```
app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){

    var clubs = {};
    url = 'https://norcalpremier.com/clubs/';

    var options = {
        uri: 'https://norcalpremier.com/clubs/',
        transform: function (body) {
            return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };

    rp(options).then(($) => {
        var ps = [];
        $("tbody tr").each(function(i, elem){
            var club_url = $(this).children().first().children().attr("href");
            club_url = url.substring(0,25) + club_url;
            console.log(club_url);
            var club_options = {
                uri: club_url,
                transform: function (body) {
                    return cheerio.load(body);
                }
            };
            ps.push(rp(club_options));
        });
        Promise.all(ps).then((results) =>{
                results.forEach((club)=>{
                    var $ = cheerio.load(club);
                    var club_name = $("h1.masthead-title").first().text().trim();
                    console.log(club_name);
                    clubs[i] = club_name;
                })
        }).then(()=>{
            fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(clubs, null, 4), function(err){
                console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
            });
            res.send('Scraping is done, check the output.json file!');
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));

    })

})
```

However, I just don't get it to work and get a bad gateway error, funnily after the console logs that the file was written. Some I assume neither the scraping is working now nor waiting for the requests to be finished.
Note: the third request is cut in this version, because I need to get the second level running first.

What I want to achieve is to get information from each of the sites on level 2 and 3, basically the name, put it into a JSON object and then write this into a file. As said previously, the scraping of the relevant data on level 2 and 3 worked in the former version, but not the writing to the file.

Thanks, your help is so much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do, make the function async and then do:

```
url = 'https://norcalpremier.com/clubs/'

// put the request code in a function so we don't repeat it
let $ = await get(url)

// get the club urls
let club_urls = $('td:nth-child(1) a[href*="/club/"]').map((i, a) => new URL($(a).attr('href'), url).href).get()

// await the responses. I used slice because I think this much concurrency will cause problems
let resolved = await Promise.all(club_urls.slice(0,2).map(club_url => get(club_url)))

// get the club names
let club_names = resolved.map($ => $("h1.masthead-title").first().text().trim())

// write the file, I think synchronously is a good idea here.
fs.writeFileSync('output.json', JSON.stringify(club_names))
```

I'll let you figure out the get function since I don't like to use request-promise

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented get the following way:
`function get(url){
 request(url, function(error, response, html){
  if(!error){
   return cheerio.load(html);
  }
 });
}`
Additionally I've put your code from above into a async function called getClubNames which I'm calling when the site is navigated, too.
However, I still get an empty output.json and an Unhandled Promise Rejection saying "$ is not a function".

Comment: I'd also be up for any other framework than request-promise, it's just one I found in a tutorial, since I am new to this.

Comment: hmm, you want it to await the request and return the resolved data as a cheerio object. So an async function.